# jQuery Spinner does not show up before the upcoming function finished loading

Tags: javascript, jquery, activity-indicator

I created two functions that should show and hide a spinner ([iOS Spinner](http://taitems.github.io/iOS-Overlay/)):

```
    var overlay;

    function startSpin() {
        var opts = {
                lines: 13, // The number of lines to draw
                length: 11, // The length of each line
                width: 5, // The line thickness
                radius: 17, // The radius of the inner circle
                corners: 1, // Corner roundness (0..1)
                rotate: 0, // The rotation offset
                color: '#FFF', // #rgb or #rrggbb
                speed: 1, // Rounds per second
                trail: 60, // Afterglow percentage
                shadow: false, // Whether to render a shadow
                hwaccel: false, // Whether to use hardware acceleration
                className: 'spinner', // The CSS class to assign to the spinner
                zIndex: 2e9, // The z-index (defaults to 2000000000)
                top: 'auto', // Top position relative to parent in px
                left: 'auto' // Left position relative to parent in px
            };
        var target = document.createElement("div");
        document.body.appendChild(target);
        var spinner = new Spinner(opts).spin(target);
        overlay = iosOverlay({
            text: "Searching ...",
            spinner: spinner
        });

        return false;
    }

    function stopSpin() {
        window.setTimeout(function() {
            overlay.update({
                icon: "img/check.png",
                text: "Success!"
            });
        }, 3e3);

        window.setTimeout(function() {
            overlay.hide();
        }, 5e3);
    }
```

So in my `process()` function I first enable the spinner, call another function that loads data from the database and after this I stop the spinner:

```
function process() {
     startSpin();
     loadData();
     stopSpin();
}
```

The `loadData()` function is quite heavy, that means it can take some seconds for it to finish.

The problem is that the spinner only shows up once the `loadData()` function finished.

Why does the spinner not show up before the `loadData()` function is called?

Comment: If `loadData()` is doing a synchronous ajax call, it's freezing everything. That's why synchronous ajax is such a bad idea.

Comment: JavaScript runs in a single thread, so like said, any synchronous operation freezes the UI